# Living creatures: 4 wings vs 6

Tags: revelation, ezekiel

Ezekiel 1:

> 5 and in the fire was what looked like **four living creatures**. In appearance their form was human, 6 but each of them had four faces and **four wings**.

Revelation 4:

> 8a Each of the **four living creatures** had **six wings** and was covered with eyes all around, even under its wings.

What is the significance of 4 wings vs 6 wings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with many of the scenes of Revelation, John is inspired to use an amalgam of more than one scene from the OT and even some mythical creatures from the Graeco-Roman pantheon (eg, Rev 13:1-5).

Rev 4 appears to be an amalgam of two scenes:

- The four cherubim of Eze 1 which had four faces, lion, ox, eagle, human, and attended the throne of God, complete with rainbow, and gleaming crystal around the throne
- The four seraphim of Isa 6 which have six wings and cry "Holy Holy Holy is the LORD of Hosts.

Note that the living creatures in Rev 4 are called neither seraphim nor cherubim.

The function of these two epiphany scenes in the OT have both similarities and differences.

- Both scenes are used to initiate someone to a sacred office - in both cases the prophets Isaiah and Ezekiel to the office of a prophet.  Rev 4 & 5 appears to be the formal enthronement scene for the Messiah after His resurrection.
- Both scenes are placed in the heavenly sanctuary as is Rev 4 & 5.
- Isa 6 describes a worship scene as does Rev 4 & 5
- Eze 1 describes a functioning government scene where God is administering affairs in some sense, surrounded by obedient attendant.  The same is seen in Rev 4 & 5.

Thus, Rev 4 & 5 imports the meaning of both Isa 6 and Eze 1.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the significance of 4 wings vs 6 wings?

They are two different classes of angel.

The four-winged creatures are cherubim, which is plural for cherub.

| Ezek. 10:20-21 |
| --- |
| <sup>20</sup>This is the living creature I saw under the God of Israel by the River Chebar, and I knew **they were cherubim**. <sup>21</sup>Each one had four faces and each one four wings, and the likeness of the hands of a man was under their wings. <sub>(*Holy Bible: New King James Version.* Nashville, Tennessee: Thomas Nelson Publishers, 1982.)</sub> |

They were also seen guarding the Tree of Life.

| Gen. 3:24 |
| --- |
| <sup>24</sup>So He drove out the man; and **He placed cherubim** at the east of the garden of Eden, and a flaming sword which turned every way, to guard the way to the tree of life. <sub>(*Holy Bible: New King James Version.* Nashville, Tennessee: Thomas Nelson Publishers, 1982.)</sub> |

This was Lucifer's class before he sinned.

| Ezek. 28:14 & 17 |
| --- |
| <sup>14</sup>"You were **the anointed cherub** who covers; I established you; you were on the holy mountain of God; you walked back and forth in the midst of fiery stones. <sup>17</sup>"Your heart was lifted up because of your beauty; you corrupted your wisdom for the sake of your splendor; I cast you to the ground, I laid you before kings, that they might gaze at you. <sub>(*Holy Bible: New King James Version.* Nashville, Tennessee: Thomas Nelson Publishers, 1982.)</sub> |

The six-winged creatures are seraphim, who stay near God's throne, singing hymns to Him.

| Isa. 6:2-3 |
| --- |
| <sup>2</sup>Above it stood **seraphim; each one had six wings**: with two he covered his face, with two he covered his feet, and with two he flew. <sup>3</sup>And one cried to another and said: "Holy, holy, holy is the LORD of hosts; The whole earth is full of His glory!" <sub>(*Holy Bible: New King James Version.* Nashville, Tennessee: Thomas Nelson Publishers, 1982.)</sub> |